# Having an issue onverting PFX to Pem

Tags: go, cryptography, pem, pfx

I'm trying to convert `PFX` to `PEM` without success due to this error:

`pkcs12: error reading P12 data: asn1: syntax error: indefinite length found (not DER)`

Searching online results in an indication to Encode `BER` to `DER` and then the `ToPEM` will not throw this annoying error.
I couldn't find any solution whatsoever.

The `pfx` file is encoded with `base64` and decoded to `[]byte` which doesn't suppose to affect the error in any case.

I don't have any option to change the `pfx` file which is inserted into this variable `config.ClusterCertificate`

***The code:***

```
blocks, err := pkcs12.ToPEM(config.ClusterCertificate, "")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var pemData []byte
    for _, b := range blocks {
        pemData = append(pemData, pem.EncodeToMemory(b)...)
    }

    // then use PEM data for tls to construct tls certificate:
    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(pemData, pemData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    _ = config

    x509cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(cert.Certificate[0])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    store.TrustStore = x509cert
    store.Certificate = &cert
```

[pfx](https://easyupload.io/wzdmb9)

`certutil dump`

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Could you post an example pfx (e.g. Base64 encoded) including password?

Comment: @Topaco I attached pfx file

Comment: Did you check if there are any anomalies in the data, e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/a/580698)

Comment: @Topaco, I added in any case even though it's a cert that is working in production.

Comment: Here is a [Go package](https://github.com/Logicalis/asn1?ref=golangrepo.com) that supports BER and DER. Maybe this is interesting for you.

Comment: @Topaco, I saw this package but couldn't manage to make it work. Any idea how to implement it correctly ? maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with this package. I posted the link because it seems to fit to your problem from its description.